# What is the point of being able to spawn dozens of processes efficiently if only very few of them can be executed in parallel?

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing, functional-programming, erlang

Erlang is very efficient in spawning new processes, but what is the point, if the CPU can only execute only e.g. 4 of them in parallel?

Therefore the rest should wait for the Erlang-"context switch".

Do you get more things done faster if you have for example 10k processes, than you would by using Java/C#/C++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many reasons:

- Conceptually, processes are easy to reason about. Asynchronous callbacks and promises in languages like JavaScript are harder to reason about because the code in the callbacks can change the values of variables used by other code in the thread.
- Processes provide isolation for the code running inside them. A process can only affect other processes by placing messages in their mailboxes. A process cannot meddle with the state of other processes.
- Processes are granular. This means:

  - If you have 400 processes on a 4 core machine the scheduler will make sure to distribute them across the threads in such a way as to fully utilize the 4 cores. One core is always going to be handling OS stuff, so the scheduler would likely end up giving the thread running on that core less work than the other 3 threads. But it adapts, so in any situation the scheduler will do it's best to make sure processes wait as little as possible and threads always have a queue of processes waiting for CPU time.
  - Moving to better hardware with more cores doesn't require changes to the code or architecture of the application. Moving your Erlang application from a 4 core machine to a 64 core machine will mean your application will run about ~16 times faster without any changes, assuming your application is structured in such a way that it can take advantage of the extra cores (usually this means making sure tasks that could be done in parallel are executed in separate processes).
- Processes are very lightweight, so there is very little overhead. In most applications the benefits provided by processes and the scheduler far outweigh the small overhead from running thousands of processes. Commodity hardware can easily handle hundreds of thousands of processes.

So in closing, whether or not processes execute in parallel isn't that important. The other benefits they provide are enough to justify their usage.